# Auto-populate field with date from another field + 14 days

Tags: javascript, date

Having searched endlessly for an answer, nothing has so far worked - so here I am hoping someone can assist.

I have 2 fields:
Action_Date & Deadline

The user updates the Action_Date field with the date they worked on the item. I then need to auto-populate the Deadline field with Action_Date + 14 days.

I have tried this so far:

```
function testCalc() {
    var actionDate = new Date(document.getElementById("Action_Date").value);
    var sla = 14;
    var deadline = actionDate + sla;
    document.getElementById("Deadline").value = deadline;
}
```

Action_Date calls this function via onblur()

The Deadline field auto-populates with the same date as Action_Date, in full format (e.g. Thu Jan 01 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0000(GMT Standard Time)14

Clearly the 14 days are not adding.  Additionally I need Deadline to show the result in dd/mm/yy.

Any ideas most welcome!

Comment: http://momentjs.com/docs/#/manipulating/add/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript dates are in milliseconds by default. So adding "14" to it is simply adding 14 milliseconds not 14 days. You will need to investigate more about Javascript Dates() here:

```
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp
```

Or use a framework of some kind like moments.js which is one of the best date handling frameworks out there. Date manipulation is one of the more complex things we developers have to do on the web due to issues with their local time, server time, etc.